# How to split a single file into multiple files based on a column in linux?

Tags: linux, files, split

I have a text file with following information:

```
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
MTHFR   TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    4524    BCM GRCh38
SLC30A1 TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    7779    BCM GRCh38
USH2A   TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    7399    BCM GRCh38
SOS1    TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    6654    BCM GRCh38
TMEM51  TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    55092   BCM GRCh38
FLG TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    2312    BCM GRCh38
FLG TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    2312    BCM GRCh38
PRDM16  TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    63976   BCM GRCh38
DNAJC11 TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    55735   BCM GRCh38
HNRNPCL2    TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    440563  BCM GRCh38
C1orf94 TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    84970   BCM GRCh38
NFYC    TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    4802    BCM GRCh38
IPP TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    3652    BCM GRCh38
```

As you see there are multiple samples I want to split the file into multiple files based on the column "Tumor_Sample_Barcode". The output files need to be named with samplename.txt.

First output - TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10.txt

```
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
MTHFR   TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    4524    BCM GRCh38
SLC30A1 TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    7779    BCM GRCh38
USH2A   TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    7399    BCM GRCh38
SOS1    TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    6654    BCM GRCh38
```

Second output - TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10.txt

```
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
TMEM51  TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    55092   BCM GRCh38
FLG TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    2312    BCM GRCh38
FLG TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    2312    BCM GRCh38
```

Third output - TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10.txt

```
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
PRDM16  TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    63976   BCM GRCh38
DNAJC11 TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    55735   BCM GRCh38
HNRNPCL2    TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    440563  BCM GRCh38
C1orf94 TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    84970   BCM GRCh38
NFYC    TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    4802    BCM GRCh38
IPP TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    3652    BCM GRCh38
```

How to do this linux?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I don't see any headers in the output files. How to get the columns names also in the outputs?

Comment: @user3351523, "headers" should be the next moment. The first moment should be your posting a testable input (as a text, not as image)

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I posted test table input as text now. How to get the headers in output files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ h=$0 }NR>1{ print (!a[$2]++? h ORS $0 : $0) > $2".txt" }' file
```

- `NR==1{ h=$0 }` - capture the 1st line/record as *header* line (`NR` points to a record number, `$0` - contains the current line)
- `NR > 1` - for all records except the first one:

  - `<cond>? <operand_1> : <operand_2>` - classical ternary operator
  - `!a[$2]++?` - check for the 1st occurrence of *barcode* value `$2` used as a key of associative array `a`
  - `h ORS $0` -  common header line concatenated with `ORS`(output record separator, defaults to `\n`) and  current record `$0`
  - `print ... > $2".txt"` - print custom content or the current line(if nothing was specified) into file `<barcode_value>.txt`

---

Or  a more self-explanatory version:

```
awk 'NR==1 {header = $0; next}
     !header_printed[$2]++ {print header > $2".txt"}
     {print > $2".txt"}' < file
```

Viewing results:

```
$ head TCGA*.txt
==> TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10.txt <==
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
MTHFR   TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    4524    BCM GRCh38
SLC30A1 TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    7779    BCM GRCh38
USH2A   TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    7399    BCM GRCh38
SOS1    TCGA-BD-A2L6-01A-11D-A20W-10    6654    BCM GRCh38

==> TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10.txt <==
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
PRDM16  TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    63976   BCM GRCh38
DNAJC11 TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    55735   BCM GRCh38
HNRNPCL2    TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    440563  BCM GRCh38
C1orf94 TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    84970   BCM GRCh38
NFYC    TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    4802    BCM GRCh38
IPP TCGA-G3-A7M5-01A-11D-A33Q-10    3652    BCM GRCh38

==> TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10.txt <==
Hugo_Symbol Tumor_Sample_Barcode    Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build
TMEM51  TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    55092   BCM GRCh38
FLG TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    2312    BCM GRCh38
FLG TCGA-O8-A75V-01A-11D-A32G-10    2312    BCM GRCh38
```

---

To adjust a filename based on 15-char sequence of *barcode* value:

```
awk 'NR==1{ h=$0 }NR>1{ print (!a[$2]++? h ORS $0 : $0) > substr($2, 1, 15)".txt" }' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! Could you please explain the command?

Comment: Please explain the command and could you also tell me how to get the output files with only 0-15 substring in the sample names like TCGA-BD-A2L6-01.txt, TCGA-G3-A7M5-01.txt and TCGA-O8-A75V-01.txt

Comment: @user3351523, yes, see my explanation